# Why is SystemJS is looking for source-map-support.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I have my whole setup here:
https://github.com/jordymeow/meowbs-2016

I believe it's quite clean, but it's not perfect. As it is, it works, but in the index.html file, try to switch those comments:

```
//System.import('./app/app');
System.import('./src/app.ts');
```

Basically, instead of using the compiled JS (performed automatically by Atom editor), we could load the app.ts directly but that doesn't work. SystemJS is looking for "source-map-support.js" and fails at it. I am not sure why I would need this dependency and I believe I have a configuration issue (or many of them).

You will probably see many things wrong in this project as well ;) Don't hesitate to tell me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have `loader: typescript` for .ts files in src, and `"typescript": "npm:typescript@2.1.1"` in the map. I'm not sure if typescript is supposed to work as a loader for systemjs, I'd suggest to use [typescript plugin for systemjs](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/) instead.

Comment: @artem I tried, and I actually committed the changes on GitHub... However, I get exactly the same error when I try.

Comment: @artem Actually I had two issues, the one you mentioned and then I had to manually add source-map-support, this way: jspm i --dev npm:source-map-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript 2.1, they added optional dependency on source-map-support - there is this function in typescript.js:

```
      tryEnableSourceMapsForHost: function() {
        try {
          require('source-map-support').install();
        } catch (e) {}
      },
```

However, SystemJS can't detect that it's optional - in order to make `require` work in the browser, it scans source code for `require` calls, tries to load all required modules, and fails.

You can install source-map-support module, or you can simply map it to [special module named](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1439) `@empty` in jspm.config.js by adding this line to `map`:

```
"source-map-support": "@empty",
```

Then you also need to add `defaultExtension: 'ts'` to `src` package config, otherwise `import { AppModule } from "./app.module";` will try to load `app.module.js`.

In all, the changed fragment in jspm.config.js looks like

```
    "src": {
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "plugin-typescript"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  map: {
    "source-map-support": "@empty",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an excellent and very complete answer! Helps so much! One more question, is using @empty recommended?

Comment: It depends  - if you are going to stick to SystemJS then it's relatively safe to assume it's going to be supported (worst case, you can register empty module with any name you want,`@null` or whatever, using SystemJS API). Otherwise, if you are confident that loading `source-map-support` in the browser is not going to break compilation, just provide it as dependency.

Comment: Little update, the dev of plugin-typescript actually fixed it by removing the dependency to source-map-support :)

Comment: If it's about [this commit](https://github.com/jspm/registry/pull/997) then yes, it should be fixed for jspm users - jspm is now aware of that dependency and will install it when installing typescript 2.1 with jspm